# N1ql join by user field

Tags: couchbase, sql++

Is it possible to join two documents in n1ql based on two fields in the document?

In the language query examples for joins, such as this:

```
SELECT c, pr
FROM purchases pu
JOIN customer c ON KEYS pu.customerId
NEST product pr
ON KEYS ARRAY li.product FOR li IN pu.lineItems END
WHERE pu.customerId = "customer1"
```

What's strange is that I can't tell what property of `c` is being used for the join, or how to specify it.

Suppose I had documents where `_type='Customer'` possessing a `myId` attribute, and I wanted to join those to documents of `_type='PurchaseOrder'`, having a `customerId` attribute.   How would that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

N1QL performs JOINs using an expression from one document that refers to the external primary key of a second document. In your example, the JOIN on customer is using the external primary key of customer c. Note that Couchbase combines a document database with a key-value database. As such, every document in Couchbase has a unique external key. That external key is what N1QL uses to JOIN the second document.

Comment: Is it planned to be an option to join by something other than that?

Comment: Yes, but not in the next release.